# How to properly close/dispose Excel COMs in C# ?(Excel process not closing)

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel, visual-studio, com

Yes, I know, it's allover the internet and probably here too, and I followed many examples and it STILL doesn't close, I'm seriously getting tired of this problem, please, if anyone could find a solution other than killing the excel process, please help me by sharing it!

My code:

```
            #region ////////// Declarations and initialisations //////////

            string[] sFilesPath = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path); // Get all files from current Path

            MSExcel.Application xlApp = null;
            MSExcel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
            MSExcel.Workbooks xlWorkBooks = null;
            MSExcel.Sheets xlSheets = null;
            MSExcel.Shapes xlShapes = null;
            MSExcel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
            MSExcel.Worksheets xlWorkSheets = null;

            xlApp = new MSExcel.Application(); xlApp.Visible = false; xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
            xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(Path + _xlNamesList[i] + ".xlsx");
            xlSheets = xlWorkBook.Sheets;

            #endregion \\\\\\\\\\ Declarations and initialisations \\\\\\\\\\

            #region ////////// Clear all previous WorkSheets //////////

            foreach (MSExcel.Worksheet Worksheet in xlSheets)
            {
                Worksheet.Cells.Clear();
                foreach (MSExcel.Shape sh in Worksheet.Shapes)
                {
                    sh.Delete();
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sh);
                }
            }
            if (xlSheets != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheets);

            #endregion \\\\\\\\\\ Clear all previous WorkSheets \\\\\\\\\\

            #region ////////// Insert each screenshot at it's respective location //////////

            foreach (string File in sFilesPath)
            {
                string sFileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(File);
                if (sFileExtension == ".jpg") // Insert each jpg file in it's coresponding place
                {
                    //--->  Declarations and initialisations
                    string sFileNameWitouthExtension = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File),
                           sShiftName = sFileNameWitouthExtension.Substring(sFileNameWitouthExtension.Length - 7),
                           sLineName = sFileNameWitouthExtension.Substring(0, sFileNameWitouthExtension.Length - 8);

                    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets[sLineName]; // Get the coresponding worksheet to edit based on LineName

                    //--->  Place the screenshot in the Excel file based on sShiftName
                    if (sShiftName == "Shift 1")
                    {
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = sFileNameWitouthExtension;
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4].Font.Size = 30;
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4].Rows.AutoFit();
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4].Columns.AutoFit();

                        xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(File, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 50, 40, 800, 500);
                    }
                    else
                        if (sShiftName == "Shift 2")
                        {
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[40, 4] = sFileNameWitouthExtension;
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[40, 4].Font.Size = 30;
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[40, 4].Rows.AutoFit();
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[40, 4].Columns.AutoFit();

                            xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(File, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 50, 650, 800, 500);
                        }
                        else
                            if (sShiftName == "Shift 3")
                            {
                                xlWorkSheet.Cells[78, 4] = sFileNameWitouthExtension;
                                xlWorkSheet.Cells[78, 4].Font.Size = 30;
                                xlWorkSheet.Cells[78, 4].Rows.AutoFit();
                                xlWorkSheet.Cells[78, 4].Columns.AutoFit();

                                xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(File, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 50, 1245, 800, 500);
                            }
                }
            }
            #endregion \\\\\\\\\\ Insert each screenshot at it's respective location \\\\\\\\\\

            #region ////////// Save EXCEL file and release/close objects //////////

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Path + _xlNamesList[i++] + ".xlsx", MSExcel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, MSExcel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, MSExcel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            xlWorkBook.Close();
            xlApp.Quit();

            if (xlShapes != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlShapes); xlShapes = null; }
            if (xlWorkSheet != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet); xlWorkSheet = null; }
            if (xlWorkSheets != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheets); xlWorkSheets = null; }
            if (xlWorkBook != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook); xlWorkBook = null; }
            if (xlWorkBooks != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBooks); xlWorkBooks = null; }
            if (xlApp != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp); xlApp = null; }

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            #endregion \\\\\\\\\\ Save EXCEL file and release/close objects \\\\\\\\\\

            #region ////////// Kill EXCEL proccess ---> DON'T WANT THIS!!! //////////

            foreach (Process Proc in Process.GetProcesses())
                if (Proc.ProcessName.Equals("EXCEL"))
                    Proc.Kill();

            #endregion \\\\\\\\\\ Kill EXCEL proccess \\\\\\\\\\
```

After I pass the GC's, the Excel process is still there :/, it's freakin driving me crazy already. Please help!!!

// EDIT: Thanks to Hans for marking it as duplicate, the other post FINALY answers my question, all the tumb rules and dots and object releases are a piece of crap, you just need to put GC's outside a method not inside...

Comment: You may call the `ReleaseComObject`-method as often as references exist on the object. To ensure that there´s no more reference just call it within a loop until it returns 0. And please remove the GC-calls. It does its work regardless of what you say the GC...

Comment: I've worked after this example, http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/05/release-excel-com-objects/ , I'll try to do as you said, in a loop, but don't know what type should be the com I'm passing to the function, like public int releaseComs(what_argument?)
{return 0;}

Comment: Altough references exist on the object while it's != null, and in my code from the post you can see I always set them to null after I ReleaseComObject. So even if I put this in a loop it will always run 1 time since I always set them to null (which is indicated to do so after u dereference it)

Comment: Setting the references to null only serves to aid automated garbage collection, it won't matter on whether your excel process remains or not (unless you set them to null *before* telling `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()` to release the object, in which case you'd be telling it to release `NULL`)

Comment: Did you omit any try/catch code from this code?

Comment: well, I haven't set any try/catch, what difference it makes? I don't have exceptions.

// EDIT: how can I check if the object still has references then?

I'm guessing this won't work will it?

        public int DereferenceComs(object myObj)
        {
            while(myObj != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myObj);
                myObj = null;
            }
            return 0;
        }

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to fetch **each and every (intermediate) object** and call `ReleaseComObject` on it. Otherwise you have something dangling that won't be released and excel won't close.

Here are some bad examples of your code that leads to those problems:

```
 xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets[sLineName];
```

With that you have a dangling reference to `Worksheets`. Better write it that way:

```
 xlWorkSheets = xlWorkBook.Worksheets;
 xlWorkSheet = xlWorkSheets[sLineName];
```

And another one:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[40, 4].Rows.AutoFit();
```

This should be better:

```
var cells = xlWorkSheet.Cells[40,4];
var rows = cells.Rows;
rows.AutoFit();
```

All this intermediate objects will then be put into an `HashSet<object>`. At the end i will then iterate over this list and call on all of them the release method.

The rule of thumb is: **If you more than one dot in your command something is wrong.**

To find such a problem i started my wrapper with only creating and closing an excel instance. Then i tested that excel opens up and immediately closes. Then i started to slowly access some objects and tested it. Between every new two lines I added I tested if excel still closes when I call the quit method. So far this is a very hard and frustrating way, but the only one to reliable clean up really all objects.

Comment: lol yeah, in the example you gave that's what I actually intended to do but I forgot, I tried as much as I could to respect the thumb rule but I got lost at some point, I'll re-see the code and try as much as I can to apply it altough I still can't seem to see how can I apply that to, let's say, the part where I add the picture as shape.

Comment: @VenomXLR: Comment all the code between `xlApp = new MSExcel.Application()` and `xlWorkBook.Close();`. Then test if excel opens and closes (it really should!). Then start to slowly uncomment your code and test if excel still closes. That's the only way i found to reliable find this f*** errors regarding to interop.